# Connect to remote MySQL database on ec2 Ubuntu machine

Tags: macos, r

I have seen a few related questions on SO, but none have helped me. I setup a MySQL database on an Ubuntu machine on EC2.  I am trying to connect to it from within R, using e..g ,

```
con <- dbConnect(MySQL(), username = user, dbname = db, host = host, password = password)
```

where the username and password are those for the remote database, and the host is the ec2 address (something like `ec2-54-456-161-6.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com` [not a real one])

Any thoughts on how to do this?

To log in to the Ubuntu machine the database is installed on from the shell on my machine I have to use the key pem file. Does this key have to be provided to authenticate? If so, how?

Comment: I don't want to edit it if it's correct but... that should be Ubuntu, not Unbuntu - correct?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the MySQL instance listens on the network, even if you're on the same machine. In `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, change this:

```
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
```

This should be in a number of MySQL tutorials and is not EC2 specific.

You want to make sure that you can connect to the DB from the server itself. Once that is taken care of, try the remote access.  If a port ends up being blocked, you can also got the route of an ssh tunnel -- which again is described in a number of tutorials.

Comment: Thanks, looking into that.

Comment: Sorry, had to sleep a while. It was an issue on the ec2 instance, had to add to the security group to allow incoming connections.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in my case was that I just need to add a new rule to the security group to allow remote connections on port 3306. See below screenshot of the rule added (the bottom line)

[image]

That was all that was needed.

Comment: Good to know you fixed. And ahh, port 8787, something makes me think I know what app uses that :)

Comment: Ha, yes indeed, I like using that port